# Kitchen faucet twisted to the left for hot water

Tags: kitchens, faucet, kitchen-sink

For some reason, now I have to turn the hot water of my kitchen faucet all the way to the left (10 o'clock) like below photo to get hot water:

[image]

The cold water is right in middle (6 o'clock).

How to fix this? Please let me know any advise.

Comment: Did anything change recently? New water heater, new faucet, etc?

Comment: @mmathis Nothing new since

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Chances are your facuet just moved. Under the sink, locate the nut that holds the faucet to the sink and loosen it. The nut should either be a large one with all the other hoses going through it or a small one on the same pipe that the sprayer connects to (if it's this design, be sure to losen the top nut and not the sprayer connection). Once loosened, adjust the faucet on the top so that the valve moves equal distance to the left and right and then retighten the nut.